# How to fill a Pandas dataframe column with values derived from a user-made function applied to the index of every row?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to generate a new column in my dataframe that is filled with the results of a user-defined function, applied to the index of every column. However, I don't know how to best do this in Pandas.

For background, I have a dataframe that lists my samples. Each of these samples has several associated .csv files in another folder that contain additional data. I would like to automatically generate a column in the dataframe that contains a list of the files that are associated with each sample. To do that, I want to compare each filename with the sample name (the index values of the dataframe) and add matching filenames to a list.

I have the feeling that df.apply() could be something I need, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work for my purposes.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
>>>df = pd.read_csv('isotope_data.csv', index_col = 'Sample')
>>>df

              d13C     d2H
Sample                    
KMa-Sah-1  -23.696 -297.40
KMa-Sah-2  -25.304 -303.86
KMa-Sah-3  -22.236     NaN
KMa-Sah-4  -23.814 -289.03
KMa-Sah-5  -21.340 -275.20
KMa-Sah-6  -19.313 -289.30
KMa-Sah-7  -23.739 -327.30
KMa-Sah-8  -21.770 -277.80
KMa-Sah-9  -23.210 -309.50
KMa-Sah-10 -24.514 -314.07
```

This is the non-functional solution I came up with so far:

```
# make the string lowercase and alphanumeric for easier comparison
def stripped(string):
    return re.sub(r'\W+', '', string).lower()

# generate a list of filenames that match a given string
def list_filenames(name, folder):
    files = listdir(folder)
    return [f'{folder}/{file}' for file in files if stripped(name) in stripped(file)]

# generate a new column with df.apply()
def make_filelist(x):
    x['Filenames'] = list_filenames(x.index, 'ftir_data')
    return x

df.apply(make_filelist)
```

This is what I'd like the end result to be like:

```
        d13C        d2H         Filenames
Sample          
KMa-Sah-1   -23.696     -297.40     [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH1_DIRECT DEPOSIT_3.CSV,...]
KMa-Sah-2   -25.304     -303.86     [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH2_DIRECT DEPOSIT_2.CSV,...]
KMa-Sah-3   -22.236     NaN         [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH3_DIRECT DEPOSIT_1.CSV,...]
KMa-Sah-4   -23.814     -289.03     [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH4_DIRECT DEPOSIT_1.CSV,...]
KMa-Sah-5   -21.340     -275.20     [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH5_DIRECT DEPOSIT_1.CSV,...]
KMa-Sah-6   -19.313     -289.30     [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH6_DIRECT DEPOSIT_1.CSV,...]
KMa-Sah-7   -23.739     -327.30     [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH7_DIRECT DEPOSIT_3.CSV,...]
KMa-Sah-8   -21.770     -277.80     [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH8_DIRECT DEPOSIT_3.CSV,...]
KMa-Sah-9   -23.210     -309.50     [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH9_DIRECT DEPOSIT_1.CSV,...]
KMa-Sah-10  -24.514     -314.07     [ftir_data/MAND_KMA-SAH10_DIRECT DEPOSIT_4.CSV...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation for `apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), you should probably do 2 things:

- Use the result of the apply to create a column in the dataframe.
- Specify the axis on which to run the `apply`.

This would give something like:

```py
df['Filenames'] = df.apply(make_filelist, axis=1)
```